# How to open Android App from gmail/email?

Tags: android, email, hyperlink, gmail

Has there any strong textway to open android application when i have mail and app package name ?

I want to open app when reset password is mailed and there have an link to go to specific app activity . I have tried but couldn't any good way .

Has there any way ?

Comment: What do you mean by "strong textway"?

Answer (score 2):

Have your app register to handle a URL in your manifest.  Then put a link to that URL in the email.  Tapping the link will then launch your app.

Comment: Please give me an example ?

Comment: @arifhasnat Numerous examples and tutorials can be found on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

This is called deeplinking. You register for a URL (or many of them) in your Manifest to declare that your app will handle them. Your app will then open if the user clicks a link matching that URL.

Comment: would you please give me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an Intent Filter to your activity tag in manifest to define your deep link. Look at this link:
https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html#adding-filters

When you are done with the deep link, clicking on any link that follows host://scheme pattern, opens your app.

Comment: I will be very pretty if you give me an example please

Comment: And this is an example:
http://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/android-deep-linking#7